# Having trouble understand the p-test for Type 1 Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus

So I'm having trouble sort of intuitively understanding why the $\int_{1}^{\infty}$$1\over{x^p}$$dx$ converges if and only if $p > 1$. Say $p = 1$. Then since $1\over x$ converges, shouldn't the area also converge?

Comment: The problem is that $\frac{1}{x}$ does not converge fast enough to $0$. Similarly the harmonic series diverges as $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge "fast enough" to $0$.

Comment: Is "fast enough" a mathematical term? Or do we just look with our eyes and say "mm that function doesn't flatline to 0 fast enough to say it converges"?

Comment: What do you mean $\frac{1}{x}$ converges? $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ diverges which means that the area under the curve $\frac{1}{x}$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is infinite.

Comment: I mean the function $1 \over x$ converges to 0 as x approaches infinity

Comment: In order for the area under the graph of the function $\frac{1}{x}$ to converge, little rectangles of elementary area for this function should be adding up to a particular number. The integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ clearly shows that's not what is happening. The area is not approaching a finite answer.

Comment: No, that's very far from being a  mathematical term. Actually this example shows that convergence of the integrand does not imply convergence of the integral. Are you familiar with the harmonic series?

Comment: No I'm not, I looked it up and the graph looks funky lol

Answer (score 0):

The integral converges if an only if $p>1$. If $p=1$ the integral diverges. The convergence or divergence is with respect to the integral, not the integrand function.

Comment: What is the difference between the integral of like $1 \over x^{1.0000001}$ and $1\over x$? If the integrand function converges, shouldn't the integral itself also converge?

Comment: Well, the difference is that 1.0000001 is greater than one. And that's all that it takes for the integral to converge, that the exponent is greater than one. You can compute the integral exactly and verify this.